# Binary list I create causes 'int' object is not callable

Tags: binary, typeerror

When I read a file from the HDD into a binary list named "data", I can get the length of the list using the following code:

```
with open("test 18.vf", "rb") as f:
data = f.read()
len = len(data)
print(len)
```

Above works with no errors

But when I try to manually create a binary list "b", the "len(b)" results in a TypeError.

```
b = b'\x76\x12\x0A\x08\x00'
lenofb = len(b)  #This line get a TypeError
print(lenofb)
```

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

1. Why is "b" an integer and causing the error?
2. Is my method of getting the length of the file correct?  (My intention is to search "data" for 4 hex bytes, when found do something, then repeat until the length "len" is reached.)

PS: 
a) I tried to indent lines 2-4 in example-1 above but the post just shows all 4 lines with the same indent.  How does one show proper indents for Python code in a post?

b) I just started learning Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have set `len = len(data)` earlier in your code.  That has hidden the normal definition of `len` (the function that calculates the length of something) with your definition of `len` (an int).  You are then trying to call that int as if it was a function.

You should use some other name instead of `len` for your local variable.

Comment: Ewan, you nailed it!  Funny how the interpreter did not flag my stupid use of "len" as a "variable name using a reserved name" as the real error.  I changed len to mylen and now everything works. I green check marked your post as the answer. --- Thanks man!